# Changing the title of Wordpress Tag Pages

Tags: wordpress, tags, title

I wish to change the title of Tags pages of my wordpress blog. What I want to do is to keep the Tag name as it's title only.

For example: If a tag name is "*Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial*" then that tag should have the same title "Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial" instead of "*Blog Name - Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial*" so what to change in this code? I have tried but showing errors like only variables name in wordpress title.

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo('name'); }elseif ( is_category() ) {
single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name'); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title();}
elseif (is_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ': '; single_post_title();}
else { wp_title('',true); } ?>
```

Comment: Check out tag.php of ur theme  remove blog and from there

Comment: The code will change depending on which theme you are using. Different themes work differently. Please post your `archive.php` or `tag.php` if it exists.

Comment: do understand what i wanna mean? please see this screen-cast http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9JU.png

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `is_tag()`.

Example:

```
if ( is_tag() ) {
    $tag = single_tag_title("", false);
    echo $tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are any SEO plugins installed in the site, it will override the 'wp_title' function. So you can manage the title string in that plugin settings.

If there are no such plugins, you can use following code:

```
    add_filter('wp_title', 'hs_tag_titles',10);

function hs_tag_titles($orig_title) {

    global $post;
    $tag_title = 'Test Title';
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        return $tag_title;
    } else {
        return $orig_title;
    }
}
```